# Publishing issue for a page data String index out of range: -7709

Tags: publishing, deployer

I'm facing a publishing issue for page.

In publication Queue:

> Deploying Failed: An unexpected error occurred processing data String index out of range: -7709

Could any one help me if you have encountered this sort of issue earlier.
Thanks!

## Here is the server log:

```
[Info  09-06-2014 14:29:28] [TCDLTransformer.setTargetLanguage(TCDLTransformer.java:220) ] Setting target language to jsp
[Debug 09-06-2014 14:29:28] [TransformProcessor.transformItem(TransformProcessor.java:194)] Transforming file E:\dev\server\work\tcm_0-275932-66560.Content\Pages\secured\private\saljstod\blanketter\forandring.xhtml source encoding UTF8
[Error 09-06-2014 14:29:28] [TransactionHandler.run(TransactionHandler.java:141)] An unexpected error occurred processing data String index out of range: -15136
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -15136
           at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
           at se.telenor.tpp.deployer.TPPTransformer.transform(TPPTransformer.java:73)
           at com.tridion.deployer.TransformProcessor.transformItem(TransformProcessor.java:204)
           at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:135)
           at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:119)
           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:81)
           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:86)
           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:58)
           at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:102)
           at com.tridion.profserv.deployer.MetaDataProcessor.process(MetaDataProcessor.java:127)
           at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.process(TransactionHandler.java:307)
           at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.commitTransaction(TransactionHandler.java:225)
           at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.handleTransaction(TransactionHandler.java:194)
           at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionHandler.run(TransactionHandler.java:108)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
           at com.tridion.util.LoggingThread.run(LoggingThread.java:120)
[Debug 09-06-2014 14:29:28] [FileResponder.done(FileResponder.java:94)
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like issue in your custom extension.

```
se.telenor.tpp.deployer.TPPTransformer.transform(TPPTransformer.java:73)
```

debug above mentioned file.